# Xcode Swift Navigation Bar on different ViewControllers

Tags: swift, xcode, label, navigationbar

I have got a label that appears in the NavigationBar when the View of the FirstViewController opens for the first time. The label shows a number that should be able to change. If I click a button on the FirstViewController the View of the SecondViewController shows up in which's NavigationBar the label of the FirstViewController is still visible. When I change the number that is written in the label by clicking on a button in the SecondViewController the number of the label only changes when I go back to the View of the FirstViewController. That is because I update the title in the ViewDidLoad String loop.
Now my question is:
I want the number of the label to be changed at the moment when I click the button in the SecondViewController, although the label was defined in the Code of the FirstViewController. The number of the label shows an amount of money.

This is the Code of the FirstViewController:

```
var moneyLabel: UILabel?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupNavigationLabel()

    let newMoney:String = String(format: "%f", money)
    updateTitle(title: "\(newMoney)")
}

func updateTitle(title: String) {
    if let myTitleView = self.moneyLabel {
        myTitleView.text = title
    }
}    

func setupNavigationLabel() {
    let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar

    let moneyFrame = CGRect(x: 300, y: 0, width:
        (navigationBar?.frame.width)!/2, height: (navigationBar?.frame.height)!)

    moneyLabel = UILabel(frame: moneyFrame)

    moneyLabel?.text = "\(money)"

    navigationBar?.addSubview(moneyLabel!)
}
```

Comment: share your code...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting use this guide and edit your question-add any code there, you are using two VCs provide code for both, are you passing data from one VC to another? are you downloading them from a server? you have to provide sufficient info-hence share the code!

Comment: added the code now

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem is with the second `ViewController` but you are not sharing any code!!! Use the below to achieve your objective.

```
class secondViewControler:UIViewController{
var money:Int
var moneyLabel:UILAbel?

override func viewDidLoad(){
self.money= //pass the amount, i dont know which way you use to store and retrieve the amount
moneyLabel.text="\(money)"

}

@IBAction updateMoney(){
//get the amount from the textfield say the output is X
money=X
moneyLabel.text="\(money)"
}
}
```